# Why is the equivalent resistance here equal to \$R_3\$?

Tags: circuit-analysis, resistors, resistance, norton

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCNfLq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The resistors are \$R_1\$ (top), \$R_2\$ (bottom left), and \$R_3\$ (bottom right).

Why is \$R_\text{equivalent}= R_\text{ab}\$ equal to \$R_3\$ here?

I thought it would be $$R_1 + \left(\frac{R_2R_3}{R_2+R_3}\right)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can redraw the circuit above as so:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1ls7z.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

So the equivalent resistance is 1/(1/R1 + 1/R2 + 1/R3) = R/3 if all resistors are equal to R.

Comment: thanks if there was another resistor R0 between A and B would the equivalent resistance between A and B be equal to that resistance R0 or what would the result be ?

Comment: The equivalent resistance of any number of resistors in parallel can be calculated by extension of the formula in my answer.  So 1/(1/R1 + 1/R2 + 1/R3 + 1/R0) = Req. If they are all equal to R it would simplify to R/4.

Comment: Oh i thought that the equivalent resistance between A and B would be equal to R0 if there was a resistor R0 between A and B